# can we use flex and c++ on android?

Tags: android, c++, apache-flex, android-ndk, flex4.5

I have created an AIR app on windows which uses flex as front end, and c++ native binaries at back end. The two are loosely coupled, and communicate with the help of flex NativeProcessEvents.

As a next step I want to port the same app over android. I do not have any prior experience of Android development, but I understand that Flex 4.5 has a good support for Android. But from whatever I read so far, the C/C++ support for Android is limited. Android NDK seems to be a way to communicate b/w native  Android Apps and c++ code, but I am not clear whether it also allows to compile "legacy c++" code to "c++ only" binaries. Is it possible?

Any links/examples on this would greatly help.

Regards,
Kapil

Comment: http://android.yongbok.net/repository/platform/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html. Using GNU libstdc++ static library, you will get all C++ features.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. The first is to re-write your C++ code to some server based language.  Visual C++ and .NEt seems like a likely candidate beacuse you should be able to reuse much of your C++ code in the port.
2. You may want to investigate [Native Extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html) feature that was announced for [AIR 3.0](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/air3/).  I believe you should be able to port your C++ code over to a Native Extension to expose that to the AIR app running on Android.  I'm unclear if you'll have to rewrite the C++ code in Java.

   AIR 3 is in release candidate stage as a few days ago, so I Expect a formal release is right around the corner.

Comment: Dear Flextras...thanks for the response. Only yesterday I also found out that Adobe has release the Native Extension feature as a part of AIR 3.0. I was really looking forward to it. But I am more worried about the C++ binaries. It is a huge legacy code, and would be quite tough for me to recode it. Any Android libraries/toolkits that can help me do it easily?

Comment: I do not know of any libraries/toolkits for porting C++ binaries to another language.  If you have the code, I would have expected that Visual C++ would allow you to recompile easily.  I'm unclear if NAtive extensions support C++, or if it has to be C.

Comment: okay thanks...will look into this and update once I find a solution to this !!

Answer (score 0):

Android's NDK is totally capable of running arbitrary C and C++ code. The real question would be the interface between AIR and C++ - unfortunately I don't have any experience with Flex on Android.

Comment: Thanks qdot....that is great. So is there a g++ for Android that can work with Makefiles and create a native binary? If so, can you please point me to some relevant links there? Regarding C++/AIR interface I know how to work that out....so that is not a worry :)